# Make image fully responsive but maintain aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive, responsive-images

I have problem where I have fully responsive webshop which works on resize, I need to make product box image to be in square box. So for example image 150x150, 150x100 and 100x150 needs to be centered by X/Y axis, without rasterizing and similar issues. I don't have option to hardcode sizes of product boxes so it must be responsive on changing width of browser.

So far I tried:

- Use 150x150 hidden placeholder in behind to maintain aspect ratio and over that add element which will contain image tag (tried width/height auto and 100%)
- Use 150x150 hidden placeholder in behind to maintain aspect ratio and over that add element which will contain element which has background image with contain/cover property, didn't work for me
- Writing script which will work on img load and create canvas to replace old image - does not work because of lazy load

so my limitations are:

- Can not use scripts because of lazy load images
- Can not hardcode sizes of image box in product box
- Can not use anything which is not supported by all browsers (for example `max-width: max-content` is not supported by IE11 and below)
- I need to use img tag which provides sizes property to have all sizes needed on different dimensions

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Google and learn about "object-fit" css property

Comment: object-fit doesn't work in IE unfortunately. But background-size cover and contain may help you. 'All browsers' is probably an impossible target, but caniuse.com will show you what CSS is supported by what browser versions.

Comment: @AHaworth I tried using background-size, but what happened here is that I got image smaller then it should be, so it got rasterized, that is why I need to use <img/> tag which will contain sizes property and load image based on width of the browser, I don't have an option to load bigger image if I get small one

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So if the image is smaller than the available area you want it to stick to being shown with its natural dimensions, and if it is bigger then to squash down into the available area.

Comment: "Supported by all browsers" isn't an attainable (or even sane) goal. IE development ended _seven years_ ago. [A Business Case for Dropping Internet Explorer](https://css-tricks.com/a-business-case-for-dropping-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple snippet where the image is given max width and height. It will not go above its natural width and height but if it is too big for the area allowed it will shrink to fit without losing its aspect ratio.

The image is centered in its parent using flex.

```css
div {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/150/200"></div>
```